# Node Express design for avoiding multiple clients in Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Building a simple app with Posts and Comments.

User hits a Post and adds a comment, everyone who's viewing that same Post will see the new comments added to the post. All done via Socket.io.

This is how I instantiate it:

```
// app.js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(app.get('port')));

var chat = io.of('/p/' + id).on('connection', function(socket) {
      socket.on('addComment', function(data) {
        var content = data.comment;
        var comment = new commentModel({
          user: req.user._id,
          post_id: id,
          content: content
        });
        comment.save(function(err, doc) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          commentModel.findById(doc._id).populate('user').exec(function(err, comment) {
            chat.emit('newComment', {
              comment: comment
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });

// client-side JS
self.socket_io = io.connect(window.location.href);
self.socket_io.on('newComment', function(data) {
    // do stuff with the new comment
};
```

The first time you hit the page, the comment is submitted once (one socket connection), however, if I refresh the page and submit a new comment, two are created (one for each connected client).

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You mean that two comments are written into the database or two comments are displayed on the page?

Comment: well, both...but they're also saved to the DB

Answer (score 0):

does 
commentModel.findById

nede to be 
comment.findByID 
?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a few of these:

Manage the socket session on the server: `socketio_session[user_id].push(session)`. 
Will give you access to all the sessions connected for a particular user. You probably don't need to store a list of sessions per user, just the latest session, and force disconnect on the existing session, before storing a new session.

--

This list a few things, including changing a config for forcing new connection
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/474

--

This might also be of use, explains how to extract session id in sockets using express:
http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Answer (score 0):

I think this one might help you out creating new socket connection each time user refresh

https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io/